# How can I compare date in my database in jsp?

Tags: database, jsp, date

all,
I am a newbie in jsp, here is my code,

```
String strArrivaldate = request.getParameter("txtArrivaldate");
// ...connection code....
String strcheck = 
    "SELECT  *  FROM tblReservation where Dt_ArrivalDate >= "+ strArrivaldate;
```

Dt_ArrivalDate is a Date field in my access database...
Anyhow its giving me error in comapring dates, tell me if either way to solve...
Please, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You should use PreparedStatements to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (security problem) and for [better performance](http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters) (in most databases). Using bind parameters means also to have less quotes--hence less chance for syntax errors in the SQL statement :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String strcheck = 
  "SELECT * FROM tblReservation where Dt_ArrivalDate >= cdate('"+ strArrivaldate +"')";
```

If does't work, post your error message here...

Comment: ava.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. is the erroe